# Tackling a sequence for it's reccurence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

What is the recurrence relation that satisfies the sequence:

$$a_n = n^2+n.$$

And, in general, what is the general approach to take to find such recurrence relation. Because, it is kind of hard to find such relation

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
a_{n+1}=a_n+2(n+1)
\end{eqnarray*}
but you could have other recuurence relations.

Comment: to add to the comment above by @DonaldSplutterwit  we have e.g. Fibonacci numbers and can define them with $a_{0}=0;a_{1}=1 ;a_{2}=1$ and $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2} = a_{n-2}+2\cdot a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}$  the second equals only holding once a certain number of terms are defined.

Comment: Or $a_n = 2 a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} + 2$ if you want a "pure" recurrence.

Comment: oh so it's called a pure reccurence

Comment: @bzal no, I don't think so, hence the quotation marks

Comment: @N.. ,Is this relation, for my question? How did you derive this?

Comment: I guessed it. Your $a_n$ starts $0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30$. Using the $n-1$ element, one has $12 = 2 \cdot 6 - 0$, $20 = 2 \cdot 12 - 4$, $30 = 2 \cdot 20 - 10$. Using the $n-2$ element for the remainder, one finds $0 = 2 - 2$, $4 = 6 - 2$, $10 = 12 - 2$, so that seems to work out. Resolving the recurrence $a_n = 2 a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} + 2$ with $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 2$ then indeed produces your formula. As others have said, it is not a general method.

Comment: wow, you must be a genius, I couldn't find that wasting 5 pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case we have:
$$
a_{n+1}=(n+1)^2+n+1=n^2+1+2n+n+1= n^2+n+2(n+1)=a_n+2(n+1)
$$

and $a_0=0$.

In general the problem con be not so simple and I don't know a general method to  to recognize in $a_{n+1}$ the previous terms.

Comment: Consider the fibionacci series, it has a very satisfiable recurrence relation, in that, it expresses  terms in terms of the sum of it's two predecessors. Is that generality necessary?

Comment: There are also recurrences of higher order, in which are used more than two predecessors.

Comment: meaning the generality should be considered in precedence of one or more?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution: $$a_{n+1}=(n+1)^2+n+1=(n^2+2n+1)+n+1=(n^2+n)+2n+2=a_n+2n+2$$

Comment: @MrYouMath, if a term in the recurrence relation is not defined in terms of it's previous terms, then is it still a recurrence relation?

Comment: A linear recurrence equation is given by $c_{n+k}a_{n+k}+c_{n+k-1}a_{n+k-1}+\ldots+c_na_n=f(n)$. The function $f(n)$ can also be nonlinear. In this case $f(n)=2n+2$.